# Network simulation

Tags: java, networking, proxy, filtering, simulation

We are doing a little project for a university course where we are to write a proxy server (in Java) that is able to filter internet traffic on the application layer.

To test it we would need a network simulator capable of running a JVM on its nodes. We will focus on HTTP traffic, so if the simulator has means to display a browser window as one endpoint would see it, that would be great.

Given these requirements, I thought it best if there would be software that allows a VM to hook up to its simulated network for choice hosts.
I found GSM3 to be a likely candidate, unfortunately we would need an IOS image for this and I do not have the means to acquire one legally.

So which simulator would you suggest?